# Could cloak wings actually evolve?

Tags: evolution

There are creatures in fiction that use their wings as cloaks: Draga in Stargate Infinity, Big Chill in Ben 10, and the gargoyles in... you know. My point is, can any of you see this evolving naturally? What would the evolutionary advantage be? Those are technically the same question since things evolve naturally if there is an evolutionary advantage.

Comment: have you ever seen a bat at rest?

Comment: @John, I would hardly call the bat's wings "a cloak". They are too thin to provide any protection.

Comment: Your question would be improved with an explanation of what you mean by "cloak."  Though references to other subjects are encouraged (Stargate Infinity, Ben 10...) they are never expected to be stand-alone, requiring people to leave the site just to figure out what you're asking about.  At this time, I don't know if you're using "cloak" in the context of a coat or cape, or the context of a Romulan ship.

Comment: I concur with **JBH**: What is the purpose of this cloak? Bats pretty much use their wings as a cloak, but it won't deflect an arrow. It keeps them warm, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Black herons already use their wings to shade the water where they are hunting.

[image: black heron using wings as shade]

This could further evolve into using them as a cloak. However...

The advantage of using a cloak is that it acts as a barrier between the outside environment and the body, protecting from it (think rain, cold, wind...).

Now, using part of your body to protect your body is not going to bring a large advantage, unless the "cost" of the protecting part is negligible when compared to the protected part. Think of a lizard tail.

I doubt that a functional wing can be considered an expendable spare part. A lizard with no tail can survive pretty fine, just having to bear with the lack of the defensive mechanism provided by its tail while the new tail regrows.

A flying creature with a damaged wing  (i.e. frozen) is going to have much more difficulties in surviving. Unless the creature has lost the ability to fly and the only purpose of the wings is to act as cloak.

Therefore, a pair of cloak-wings would be advantageous for a non flying creature living in cold climate, where the cloak could provide additional shielding from wind/snow/cold.

Comment: I first thought of some cooling looking cloaked birds in the antarctic winter, but then I realized only penguins live in the antarctic year round. So chances are they would evolve to lose the wing and develop more fat. Maybe something along the lines of the Heron, where it provides an indirect benefit or cool factor, rather than a survival mechanic would be more plausible.

Comment: @Shadowzee, not necessarily Antarctica. Tundra, high mountain or long cold winter can provide sufficient pressure to make such an adaptation plausible

Comment: Thanks for your insight. These might just be the ideas to fully realize this.